# Depois da atualização 0.7.0 do firebase_auth não consigo mais fazer login com o Google. Como que prossigo para logar com o google+firebase?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

Depois que o usuario usava a opção de login do Google usava esse codigo, mas após atualizar a bibliote do `firebase_auth` para a versão 0.8.0+1 esse codigo quebrou:

```
var fUser = await fAuth.linkWithGoogleCredential(
        idToken: userGoogleAuthentication.idToken,
        accessToken: userGoogleAuthentication.accessToken);
```

e retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Error: The method 'linkWithGoogleCredential' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseAuth'.
 - 'FirebaseAuth' is from 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'
```

Não achei no github da lib como fazer, lá está mo mostrando exatamente como estou fazendo.

Answer (score 0):

Depois de olhar no código fonte da lib vi que o metodo `linkWithGoogleCredential` foi substituido por `linkWithCredential` que recebe um `AuthCredential` a lib fornece algumas classes que retornam um `AuthCredential`.

Que são:

- `GoogleAuthProvider`
- `FacebookAuthProvider`
- `PhoneAuthProvider`
- `EmailAuthProvider`
- `GitHubAuthProvider`
- `TwitterAuthProvider`

Agora com a alteração o código ficou assim:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

var fUser = await fAuth.linkWithCredential(GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
            idToken: userGoogleAuthentication.idToken,
            accessToken: userGoogleAuthentication.accessToken));
```